# Not able to open the URL using the driver.get method in Selenium after launching the Firefox browser?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I am new to Selenium. I have written a simple script using Junit/Selenium that opens a browser, opens a URL and then quits the browser. But the script isn't working.

Although the browser is launched nothing happens after that. I read on-line that maybe I need to add the latest Selenium jar file in the package but that didn't help either!

```
package pack1;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TC01 {


WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void launchBrowser(){

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();


    driver.manage().window().maximize();


    driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
}

@Test
public void atTest(){

}

@After
public void quitBrowser(){
    driver.quit();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this configuration:
Firefox 47.1
or
Firefox ESR 45.3.0

[Firefox ESR download page](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/)

```
driver.navigate().to("http://sqa.stackexchange.com");
```

If you are using maven then try this at pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you want to check if all system variables are set properly.

[GitHub | Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template](https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template)

Comment: I have edited my question with the code. My Firefox version is 47.0.1 still the code isn't working.

Comment: Are you using maven?
Also did you tried to run "Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template" ?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this and give the feedback..

```
 package pack1;

 import org.junit.After;
 import org.junit.Before;
 import org.junit.Test;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TC01 {


 WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void launchBrowser(){

 System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","pathToGeckodriver");
   FirefoxDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();


driver.manage().window().maximize();


driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
 }

 @Test
 public void atTest(){

  }

  @After
  public void quitBrowser(){
  driver.quit();
  }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the driver version of it is compatible with Firefox version you are using
2. Use `system.set.property("marinotte", true)`
3. Use profile function before calling the URL

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

1. initialize driver in `@before`
2. and call `driver.get()` in `@test`